# Why has IIS 8.0 Detailed error page suddenly started to show up when I have custom errors on?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Errormessage says the following:
`HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`

Why has my application suddenly started to do that?
In my web.config I've defined the following:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404"/>
</customErrors>
```

Whenver I built my solution from a cshtml file before, this redirected me to a custom error page whereas now it just displays the IIS 8.0 Detailed error page.

When I say built from a cshtml file, I mean that I did ctrl+F5 and my browser would open a new tab in `http://localhost:54837/Views/UnitDetails/Wireline.cshtml`. This gave me the custom 404 page, but now like I said, it just gives me the IIS 8.0 Detailed error page.

Hopefully someone can point me to the error source, as this is really annoying! :p

Comment: Why do you think a 500.19 error should redirect to a 404 error page?

Comment: @ErikPhilips That's another question. I'm simply wondering why the error is occuring and is presented in another way than it was before.

Comment: IIS doesn't *randomly* decide to throw 500.19 or 404 or 310.  The error you experienced before *has to be* a different error than this, simply because a 500.19 is not a 404.

Comment: I get that it doesn't throw randomly. Guess I'll have to retrace some steps on the web.config file and have a look at your suggested duplicate question. Thanks for your help. Also, this question can be closed :)